# How to run golang tests sequentially?

Tags: testing, go

When I run `go test`, my output:

```
--- FAIL: TestGETSearchSuccess (0.00s)
        Location:       drivers_api_test.go:283
        Error:          Not equal: 200 (expected)
                                != 204 (actual)

--- FAIL: TestGETCOSearchSuccess (0.00s)
        Location:       drivers_api_test.go:391
        Error:          Not equal: 200 (expected)
                                != 204 (actual)
```

But after I run `go test` again, all my tests pass.

Tests fail only when I reset my mysql database, and then run `go test` for the first time.

For every `GET` request, I do a `POST` request before to ensure that there is data created in the DB.

Could anyone help me with how to make sure that tests are run sequentially? That is the `POST` requests are run before the `GET` requests?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can't / shouldn't rely on test execution order. The order in which tests are executed is not defined, and with the use of [testing flags](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Description_of_testing_flags) it is possible to exclude tests from running, so you have no guarantee that they will run at all.

For example the following command will only run tests whose name contains a `'W'` letter:

```
go test -run W
```

Also note that if some test functions mark themselves eligible for parallel execution using the [`T.Parallel()`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#T.Parallel) method, the go tool will reorder the tests to first run non-parallel tests, and then run parallel tests in parallel under certain circumstances (controlled by test flags like `-p`). You can see examples of this in this answer: [Are tests executed in parallel in Go or one by one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44325232/are-tests-executed-in-parallel-in-go-or-one-by-one/44326377#44326377)

Tests should be *independent* from each other. If a test function has prerequisites, that cannot be done/implemented in another test function.

**Options to do additional tasks before a test function is run:**

- You may put it in the test function itself
- You may put it in a package `init()` function, in the `_test.go` file itself. This will run once before execution of test functions begins.
- You may choose to implement a [`TestMain()`](http://golang.org/pkg/testing/#pkg-overview) function which will be called first and in which you may do additional setup before you call [`M.Run()`](http://golang.org/pkg/testing/#M.Run) to trigger the execution of test functions.
- You may mix the above options.

In your case in package `init()` or `TestMain()` you should check if your DB is initialized (there are test records inserted), and if not, insert the test records.

Note that starting with Go 1.7, you may use subtests in which you define execution order of subtests. For details see blog post: [Using Subtests and Sub-benchmarks](https://blog.golang.org/subtests), and the package doc of the [`testing`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Subtests_and_Sub_benchmarks) package.

Comment: This makes sense for unit tests, where you are testing mocked data sources, but when you have an integration test, making the integration tests run sequentially may be a reasonable requirement.

Comment: For integration tests from different packages this can be achieved with `go test -p 1 ...` (see other answer).

Answer (score 44):

For those who as I am is getting problems because of multiple concurring tests running simultaneously. I found a way to limit the maximum number of test running in parallel:

```sh
go test -p 1
```

With this, your test will run sequentially one by one.

[Source](https://medium.com/@teivah/how-to-run-go-tests-sequentially-a2a206e223b)

Comment: Thank you for answering the question.

Comment: There are two different flags. The `-parallel N` allows parallel execution of tests marked with a call to `t.Parallel()`. This applies to tests within the **same package**.  However, the documentation also contains a comment that tests from **different packages** may be run in parallel according to the setting of the `-p` flag. The `-p` flag specifies the number of programs, such as build commands or test binaries, that can be run in parallel.

Comment: This is actually a great answer if you have tests that interact with a database.

Answer (score 24):

Apart for 3rd party libraries like [Convey](https://github.com/smartystreets/goconvey) and [Ginkgo](https://github.com/onsi/ginkgo), with plain Golang 1.7 you can run tests sequentially. You can read more [here](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Subtests_and_Sub_benchmarks)

```
func TestFoo(t *testing.T) {
    // <setup code>
    t.Run("A=1", func(t *testing.T) { ... })
    t.Run("A=2", func(t *testing.T) { ... })
    t.Run("B=1", func(t *testing.T) { ... })
    // <tear-down code>
}
```

And you can run them conditionally with:

```
go test -run ''      # Run all tests.
go test -run Foo     # Run top-level tests matching "Foo", such as "TestFooBar".
go test -run Foo/A=  # For top-level tests matching "Foo", run subtests matching "A=".
go test -run /A=1    # For all top-level tests, run subtests matching "A=1".
```

So lets say you got an `user` package from a REST api that you want to test. You need to test the create handler in order to be able to test the login handler. Usually I would have this on the `user_test.go`

```
type UserTests struct { Test *testing.T}
func TestRunner(t *testing.T) {

    t.Run("A=create", func(t *testing.T) {
        test:= UserTests{Test: t}
        test.TestCreateRegularUser()
        test.TestCreateConfirmedUser()
        test.TestCreateMasterUser()
        test.TestCreateUserTwice()
    })
    t.Run("A=login", func(t *testing.T) {
        test:= UserTests{Test: t}
        test.TestLoginRegularUser()
        test.TestLoginConfirmedUser()
        test.TestLoginMasterUser()
    })

}
```

Then I can append methods to the UserTest type that wont be executed by the `go test` command in any `_test.go` file

```
func (t *UserTests) TestCreateRegularUser() {
    registerRegularUser := util.TableTest{
        Method:      "POST",
        Path:        "/iot/users",
        Status:      http.StatusOK,
        Name:        "registerRegularUser",
        Description: "register Regular User has to return 200",
        Body: SerializeUser(RegularUser),
    }
    response := util.SpinSingleTableTests(t.Test, registerRegularUser)
    util.LogIfVerbose(color.BgCyan, "IOT/USERS/TEST", response)
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the order is actually controlled by grouping the tests this way? The docs say that you can control paralellism but not that they will necessarily be run in the order that `t.Run` is called.  Race conditions are so hard to verify... I will reply back if I find any definitive evidence either way.

Comment: @threeve they run sequentially for sure. You are basically running a single test this way.

Comment: t.Run() by definition runs tests in a goroutine, are you sure?

Comment: @Alaska apparently yes! https://pkg.go.dev/testing#T.Run It's a goroutine but blocks by default. Why goroutine then you ask? Because you _can_ combine it with `t.Parallel` to make it parallel

Comment: Sorry, I don't think this is the case, Please try this with 10000 test runs and most likely you will see intermittent errors if you rely on the order of test case execution

Answer (score 3):

The best way to achieve that is to create a `TestMain`, as presented [here](http://golang.org/pkg/testing/#pkg-overview).

```
import (
  "testing"
  "os"
)

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
   // Do your stuff here
   os.Exit(m.Run())
}
```

Comment: Explain what this is supposed to do. Still doesn't solve the issue

Answer (score 2):

It's also possible to synchronize the test using wait groups:

```
    awaitRootElement := sync.WaitGroup{}
    awaitRootElement.Add(1)

    t.Run("it should create root element", func(t0 *testing.T) {
        // do the test which creates root element
        awaitRootElement.Done()
    })
    awaitRootElement.Wait()
    t.Run("it should act on root element somehow", func(t0 *testing.T) {
      // do tests which depend on root element
    })
```

Note that you should wait *before* scheduling the tests, since the asynchronous test execution otherwise might deadlock (the test routine is awaiting another test which never gets to run).