# Are tests executed in parallel in Go or one by one?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, go

I have a Go file with unit tests and some of them use a common variable. Another global variable is used in the code that I'm testing. All of this can cause a problem.

In Go when we execute tests that are located in the same file how does they run? In parallel or next one will not start before previous one is finished ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's really easy to test it:

```
func Test1(t *testing.T) {
    fmt.Println("Test1 start")
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
    fmt.Println("Test1 end")
}

func Test2(t *testing.T) {
    fmt.Println("Test2 start")
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
    fmt.Println("Test2 end")
}

func Test3(t *testing.T) {
    fmt.Println("Test3 start")
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
    fmt.Println("Test3 end")
}
```

Running it with `go test`, the output shows it's sequential:

```
Test1 start
Test1 end
Test2 start
Test2 end
Test3 start
Test3 end
```

So normal tests are executed one after the other, sequentially, but don't forget that order is not defined: [How to run golang tests sequentially?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201858/how-to-run-golang-tests-sequentially/31204016#31204016)

Also note that a test function can mark itself eligible for parallel execution, paralell with other tests that also do the same using the [`T.Parallel()`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#T.Parallel) method:

> Parallel signals that this test is to be run in parallel with (and only with) other parallel tests.

So if we modify the above testing code to:

```
func Test1(t *testing.T) {
    t.Parallel()
    fmt.Println("Test1 start")
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
    fmt.Println("Test1 end")
}

func Test2(t *testing.T) {
    t.Parallel()
    fmt.Println("Test2 start")
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
    fmt.Println("Test2 end")
}

func Test3(t *testing.T) {
    fmt.Println("Test3 start")
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
    fmt.Println("Test3 end")
}
```

Running it again with `go test`, the output is:

```
Test3 start
Test3 end
Test1 start
Test2 start
Test2 end
Test1 end
```

What does this prove? The order of tests is not defined, `Test3` was executed first this time. And then `Test1` and `Test2` were run *parallel*.

There are some testing flags that control parallel execution. For example the `-parallel` flag specifies how many of these may run parallel. If you execute it with `go test -parallel=1`, the output will again become sequential, but the order will be `Test3`, `Test1`, `Test2`.

Also note that [Go 1.7 introduced subtests and subbenchmarks](https://golang.org/doc/go1.7#testing). You can read more about this in blog post [Using Subtests and Sub-benchmarks](https://blog.golang.org/subtests):

> In Go 1.7, the `testing` package introduces a Run method on the [T](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#T.Run) and [B](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#B.Run) types that allows for the creation of subtests and sub-benchmarks. The introduction of subtests and sub-benchmarks enables better handling of failures, fine-grained control of which tests to run from the command line, control of parallelism, and often results in simpler and more maintainable code.

Subtests and subbenchmarks may run parallel, and there are a number of flags that may control their execution, e.g. `-parallel`, `-p`, `-cpu`. Run `go help testflag` to see the complete list of testing flags.

Answer (score 20):

By default, all the tests **within** a package are run sequentially.

Also by default, all of the **sets of tests** are run in parallel.

This may cause issues if you use defaults and have different packages that test against a common persistence layer (like a rdbms).  If you have issues with this case, then running `go test ./... -p 1` will prevent different test suites from running concurrently.

Comment: See also: https://coderwall.com/p/rwgo_a/go-test-package-in-parallel,  https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11521, and https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/777f99/parallel_tests_on_package_level/

Comment: How does a set of tests look like ?