# Seed random number for unit tests in golang

Tags: testing, go, random

I have functions that uses `math/rand` to "randomly" sample from a Poisson and another from the binomial distribution. It is often used by other functions that also return random values like `h(g(f()))` where `f()` `g()` and `h()` are random functions.

I placed a `rand.Seed(n)` call in `main()` to pick a different seed every time the program is run and it works fine.

My question is for unittests for these PRNG functions and the functions that use them using the builtin `testing` package. I would like to remove the randomness so that I can have a predictable value to compare with.

Where is the best place to place my constant value seed to get deterministic output? At the init() of the test file or inside every test function, or somewhere else?

Comment: In each TestXY function. Otherwise you cannot run them individually with deterministic randomness via go test -run XYZ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should certainly not put it in the test `init()` function. Why? Because execution order (or even if test functions are run) is non-deterministic. For details, see [How to run golang tests sequentially?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201858/how-to-run-golang-tests-sequentially/31204016#31204016)

What does this mean?

If you have 2 test functions (e.g. `TestA()` and `TestB()`) both of which test functions that call into `math/rand`, you don't have guarantees if `TestA()` is run first or `TestB()`, or even if any of those will be called. And so random data returned by `math/rand` will depend on this order.

A better option would be to put seeding into `TestA()` and `TestB()`, but this may also be insufficient, as tests may run parallel, so the random data returned by `math/rand` may also be non-deterministic.

To really have deterministic test results, functions that need random data would need to receive a [`math.Rand`](https://golang.org/pkg/math/rand/#Rand) value and use that explicitly, and in tests you can create separate, distinct `math.Rand` values that will not be used by other tests, so seeding those to constant values and using those in the tested functions, only then can you have deterministic results that will not depend on how and in which order the test functions are called.

Comment: I've also thought about that but I didn't want to go all in and refactor just yet. 
If passing a seed explicitly, is there a hit to setting the random seed every time the function is called? Also if creating an instance of rand that generates random number, will the functions still be safe to run concurrently? Thanks

Comment: @kentwait Global functions of the `rand` package are safe for concurrent use, methods of `rand.Rand` are not, because the latter uses a non-safe source, while the former uses a safe source. If you use `rand.Rand`, create a distinct, separate value for each goroutine, or else you have to synchronize access to it manually.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to passing in a `math.Rand` you could monkey patch *IF* you you don't want dependency injection to be part of your package's API e.g.: https://play.golang.org/p/cIGxhO0wSbo

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. I didn't consider monkey-patching in golang before even if I always use this method in Python. In your example, you monkey-patched `rand.Int` to test a function `f(x)` that gets the random number from `math/rand` builtin. So if there is another random function `g(x)` that depends on `f(x)` such that `g(f(x))`, then I monkey-patch `f(x)` to make the output of `f(x)` constant right?

Comment: Nitpicking here, but most people don't call these monkey patches. Monkey patches are much much more... monkey. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38732121/122727

Answer (score 0):

To stay compatible with parallel test execution, create your own rand.Rand.

My example includes `Check()` from the standard package `testing/quick` which is often used to execute tests on a hundred of pseudo-random arguments. (Similarly to OP's case, it's a function that makes your tests very much dependent on RNG seeding).

```golang
package main

import (
    "math/rand"
    "testing"
    "testing/quick"
)

func TestRandomly(t *testing.T) {
    r := rand.New(rand.NewSource(0))
    config := &quick.Config{Rand: r}

    assertion := func(num uint8) bool {
        // fail test when argument is 254
        return num != 254
    }

    if err := quick.Check(assertion, config); err != nil {
        t.Error("failed checks", err)
    }
}
```